# Problems generating Rails route for weird URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a URL that looks like this:

```
https://host.com/imageviewer/namespace.001.587#page/1/mode/2down
```

I need to generate a rails route for this such that I can get `namespace.001.587` out as the `id` and get it to route to the `ImageViewer#show_image` action, I also need to get `2down` as the mode, and `1` as the page.  Not being a clean RESTful URL, I'm finding this difficult to do in Rails. I'm only calling `GET` on this URL.

How would you generate this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The server is never sent the hash (ie. anything after the #). That's a client side only thing. So you'll need to adjust the url or url escape the # to make it work.